# Error contains no argument packs when redefine a macro

Tags: c++, c, debugging, logging, macros

I use this macro for debug

```
#define DEBUG2(x, args ...)     printf("DEBUG2: %12s:%10s:%20s:%4d:%40s:%12u:" x "\n", \
                                        __DATE__, __TIME__, __FILENAME__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, \
                                        (uint_t) pthread_self(), ##args)
```

and use redefine

```
#define debugdb2(x, args ...)       DEBUG2(x, args ...)
```

but i get eror: expansion pattern 'xxx' contains no argument packs.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: You should edit your question to remove the request for a recommendation of logging framework.  That's not a suitable question for this site.

Comment: Please post a complete example that we can compile to show the error.